# Cyclic permutations in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

I am following a book about general relativity that explains how to compute the christoffel symbols in terms of the metric. In one step the author does a cyclic permutation of indices $(i,j,n)$ in the following equation

$$\begin{align*}\partial_ng_{ij} = g_{pj}\Gamma^p_{in}+g_{ki}\Gamma^k_{jn}\end{align*}$$

to get three independent equations. I'm new to general relativity and I'm not sure why this is allowed here.

Comment: The equation you wrote is a tensor equation, corresponding to 4x4x4=64 equations indeed, some linearly dependent from because of the symmetry of the metric. No need for index permutation to get them. Could you show us the 3 independent equations the author get? Maybe he's permuting indices before linearly combining some of the independent equations.

Comment: the three equations are the one in my post and the two you get by cyclic permutations:
$\partial_ig_{nj}=g_{pn}\Gamma^p_{ji}+g_{kj}\Gamma^k_{ni}$
and 
$\partial_jg_{in}=g_{pi}\Gamma^p_{nj}+g_{kn}\Gamma^k_{ij}$

Comment: ok, but until you provide some value to non-dummy indices, the 3 equations above tell you exactly the same thing, like $a_{ik} = b_{ik}$ tells you exactly the same thing as $a_{ki} = b_{ki}$, until you select a set of non dummy indices, as an example saying $i=1$, $k=2$ ($i=1$, $k=2$ in the first equation would correspond to $i=2$, $k=1$ in the second equation, that would correspond to "first index"=1 and "second index"=2, so that de definitions "first" and "second" indices are independent on the letters you choose to identify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Metric tensor.** The metric tensor equal to the identity

$g\hspace{-4pt}g = g_{ij} \mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j =  g^{ij} \mathbf{b}_i \mathbf{b}_j = \mathbb{I} $,

since you can prove that $g\hspace{-4pt}g \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$. If you don't believe it, evaluate the dot product of the metric tensor with the vector field, written in the natural basis $\mathbf{v} = v^k \mathbf{b}_k$, see below).

**Preliminaries: vector bases.**
The vectors of the natural basis are the derivative of the position in the space (in relativity, spacetime) w.r.t. the coordinates used to describe it,

$\mathbf{b}_i(q^k) = \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial q^i}(q^k)$,

while the components of the metric tensor are the dot-product of these vectors

$g_{ij}(q^k) = \mathbf{b}_i (q^k) \cdot \mathbf{b}_j (q^k)$.

Dual basis $\mathbf{b}^j$ is defined s.t. $\mathbf{b}^j \cdot \mathbf{b}_i = \delta_i^j$, and it's quite easy to prove

$\mathbf{b}_i = g_{ij}\mathbf{b}^j \qquad , \qquad \mathbf{b}^i = g^{ij}\mathbf{b}_j$,

being $g^{ij} = \mathbf{b}^i \cdot \mathbf{b}^j$.

It readily follow the relation between the symbols $g_{ij}$ and $g^{ij}$, as an example, evaluating the dot product of both sides of the expression $\mathbf{b}_i = g_{ij}\mathbf{b}^j$ with the vector $\mathbf{b}^k$,

$\mathbf{b}_i \cdot \mathbf{b}^k = g_{ij}\mathbf{b}^j  \cdot \mathbf{b}^k \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \delta_i^k = g_{ij} g^{jk}$.

**Christoffel symbols.**

Christoffel symbols are defined as the components of the derivatives of the vectors of the natural basis, w.r.t. the coordinates,

$\mathbf{b}_{i,j} = \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{b_i}}{\partial q^j} = \Gamma_{ij}^l \mathbf{b}_l$,

and you can evaluate it as (dot-product by $\mathbf{b}^k$ of the equation above), $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{b_i}}{\partial q^j} \cdot \mathbf{b}^k$.

Exploiting the definition of vectors of the dual basis, $\mathbf{b}^j \cdot \mathbf{b}_i = \delta_i^j$, we can evaluate its differential to evaluate the derivatives of the dual basis w.r.t. coordinates

$0 = (\mathbf{b}^j \cdot \mathbf{b}_i)_{,l} = \mathbf{b}^j_{,l} \cdot \mathbf{b}_i + \mathbf{b}^j \cdot \mathbf{b}_{i,l} = \mathbf{b}^j_{,l} \cdot \mathbf{b}_i + \Gamma_{il}^k \mathbf{b}^j \cdot \mathbf{b}_{k} = \mathbf{b}^j_{,l} \cdot \mathbf{b}_i + \Gamma_{il}^k \delta^j_k =  \mathbf{b}^j_{,l} \cdot \mathbf{b}_i + \Gamma_{il}^j$,

and thus $\mathbf{b}^j_{,l} = - \Gamma_{il}^j \mathbf{b}^i$.

**Derivative of the metric tensor.** Since it's equivalent to identity, its derivatives are equal to zero. Let's evaluate the derivative of the metric tensor w.r.t. to the coordinate $q^l$

$0 = \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{g\hspace{-4pt}g}}{\partial q^l} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial q^l}(g_{ij} \mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j) = 
g_{ij,l} \mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j + g_{ij} \mathbf{b}^i_{,l} \mathbf{b}^j + g_{ij} \mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j_{,l}$.

Using the formula for the derivative of vectors of the dual basis above, we can write,

$0 =  
g_{ij,l} \mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j - g_{ij} \Gamma_{kl}^i \mathbf{b}^k \mathbf{b}^j - g_{ij} \mathbf{b}^i \Gamma_{kl}^j \mathbf{b}^k$,

and choosing the dummy indices s.t. the vectors result $\mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j$, we get

$0 =  
( g_{ij,l} - g_{kj} \Gamma_{il}^k  - g_{ik}  \Gamma_{jl}^k  ) \mathbf{b}^i \mathbf{b}^j$.

Being valid for every choice of coordinates, all the components (the content of the parentheses) must be equal to zero. Exploiting the symmetry of the components of the metric tensor, we eventually get the desired relation

$0 = g_{ij,l} - g_{jk} \Gamma_{il}^k  - g_{ik}  \Gamma_{jl}^k \qquad \rightarrow \qquad  g_{ij,l} = g_{jk} \Gamma_{il}^k  + g_{ik} \Gamma_{jl}^k$.

I tried to start from the basics, and go through the whole derivation. Hope it helps.